# How do I read in a file, each line being an element in an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, readfile

I want to take a txt file and make each line of that file an element in an ArrayList in order. I also dont want the "\n" at the end of each line. How would I go about this?

Comment: Unless you expect code from someone, there's not much to add as your question has all the steps.

Comment: Ive tried reading the file in with a scanner, but idk how to say "take line one and make that element 0, and so on, until you reach the end of the file"

Comment: @cheesery. You can make use of a while loop. Iterate till the end of file. And add each line to your list. don't worry about index.

Comment: @cheesery. You should mark the answers for your questions as accepted more frequently. Of course, if you got the answer that you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

I found this, which can be made with JDK7:

```
List<String> readSmallTextFile(String aFileName) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get(aFileName);
    return Files.readAllLines(path, ENCODING);
}
```

And call it with

```
ArrayList<String> foo = (ArrayList<String>)readSmallTextFile("bar.txt");
```

After this, you can filter any unwanted chars in each of the lines in the List "foo".

Comment: +1 I didn't know that, on the othere hand it's not quarantied that returned is ArrayList, if I'm implementer of that method I'd use LinkedList...

Comment: @Betlista: If you want you can specify the return value as ArrayList<String> although I do not see why I should dictate the implementation.

Comment: No, you cannot, `Files.readAllLines()` returns `List<String>`, according to source code (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/nio/file/Files.java#Files.readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path%2Cjava.nio.charset.Charset%29) they are using ArrayList, but they do not need to in future...

Comment: @Campfire. Why not just keep the reference type as `List`, and that way no typecasting would be needed.

Comment: @RohitJain: I don't know. I'm perfectly fine with `List<String>`, it was _cheeserys_ requirement in the first place.

Comment: @Campfire. Well his requirement is perfectly fine. You are still fulfilling it. You cannot instantiate a `List` object. But it is generally a good idea to have an `interface` as reference pointing to the instance of implementing class.

Answer (score 1):

This requires three simple steps: -

- Read each line from your file
- Strip the newline from the end
- Add the line to the `ArrayList<String>`

You see, I didn't answer your question. I just re-framed it, to look like an answer.

This is how your `while` loop condition will look like: -

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(yourFileObj);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

    // nextLine automatically strips `newline` from the end
    String line = scanner.nextLine();  

    // Add your line to your list.
}
```

**UPDATE**: -

Since you reading your `file` line by line, it would be better to use `BufferedReader`. **Scanner** is better if you want to **parse** `each` tokens and do something special with them.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fileName"));

String line = null;

// readLine also doesn't include the newline in the line read
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
    //add your line to the list
}
```

Comment: @cheesery. You can make use of the while loop I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer BufferedReader, it's quicker than Scanner

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
```

reading until end of file is

```
String line = br.readLine(); // read firt line
while ( line != null ) { // read until end of file (EOF)
    // process line
    line = br.readLine(); // read next line
}
```